# Actionbar's menu is getting left on small screen's phones

Tags: android, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer

My app has a navigation drawer with 2 action butto on the right part of the `Actionbar`, but on device which has a screen <= 4" the result is:

[image]

The right position of the menu is:

[image]

**Edit:** including the last release of support library takes on the correct drawer's function, but the two buttons and the title still have the problem on the images.

**Edit 2:** I've spotted the problem, the second item is a complex item, formed by `ImageButton` and `TextView`. In particular, the problem is `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"` to get the badge at the top right corner. How can i get the same result of a top-right-bell notification without using alignParentRight?
Here there's the `xml` :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp" android:paddingTop="3dp" android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:paddingBottom="3dp">
<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/myButton"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:background= "@drawable/alert_empty2"
        android:onClick="openNot"/>
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textOne"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="15dp"
        android:text="0"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/badge_circle"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"/>
```